# if-elseを用いた数値の判別が、意図した通り動かない

Tags: c

任意の数字を入力して、以下の条件で値を判別するプログラムを作っています。

- 偶数で100以上
- 偶数で100未満
- 奇数で99未満
- それ以外

しかし、何を入れても`a`は「偶数かつ100以上」になります。なぜでしょうか。

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int a;
  scanf("%d", &a);

  if (a % 2 == 0 && a >= 100) {
    printf("aは偶数かつ100以上");
  }
  else if (a % 2 == 0 && a < 100) {
    printf("aは偶数かつ100未満");
  }
  else if (a % 2 == 1 && a >= 99) {
    printf("aは奇数かつ99以上");
  }
  else {
    printf("それ以外");
  }
}
```

Comment: ご質問に記載されたような事象は再現できませんでした。試し方に問題があるのかもしれません。どんな環境で実行し、どのように値を与えたか、ご質問を編集して情報を追加してみていただけませんか。

Comment: ところで3番目「奇数で99未満」は `(a % 2 == 1 && a < 99)` ではないでしょうか？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。もう一度コンパイルしたらできました。